# Errno 5 input/output error // tried probably everything

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

I wanted to install elementary OS Hera, but failed numerous times. I get the "errno 5 input/output" error during installation. I searched through forums and what not and tried everything they mentioned:

**1. Flashing ISO & DD both;**
**2. Checking for damaged sectors (none);**
**3. Using Ext4 & Ext3 both;**
**4. Installing directly and through "Try Elementary";**
**5. Checking HASH in rufus (it's the same);**
**6. Tried the commands in the terminal** (ubiquity --no-migration-assistant);
**7. Testing RAM for problems (none);**
**8. Secure boot is off**

Maybe the only thing I haven't tried is installing with a CD. I forgot to mention I am using a 1TB USB flash drive.

I have a laptop "*Toshiba Satellite p50-c-169*".

PS: NTFS file system + GPT partition

Answer (score 1):

Solution

I had the same issue and i tried the following things.

- Downloading the iso again
- Did hash check and found it's ok
- Recreate the USB using Unetbootin, then Startup disk creator

But none of the above worked. 
Finaly what worked was, **i wrote the image to a DVD using Brasero and tried. It worked like charm.**